# Why are missing `Set` for certain types a runtime error rather than compile error?

Tags: vba

Given the following VBA code, assuming that a `Something` is just a VBA class module....

```
Public Type Foo
    SomeThing As Something
End Type

Public Sub TestFoo()
    Dim x As Foo
    With x
        'Correct way to do it
        Set .someThing = New Something
    End With

    With x
        'This is wrong but realized only as a RTE 
        '438: Object doesn't support this property or method
        .SomeThing = New Something
    End With
End Sub
```

In contrast, if you change the type to something like `VBA.Collection` as below:

```
Public Type Foo
    SomeThing As VBA.Collection
End Type

Public Sub TestFoo()
    Dim x As Foo

    With x
        .SomeThing = New VBA.Collection
    End With
End Sub
```

This is now a compile error, with `Argument Not Optional`. This is obviously wrong but *why* is it a compile-time error only with `VBA.Collection`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in the VBA Language Specification.  The semantics of the assignment inside the `With` block is driven by whether or not the statement is a `Set` statement or a `Let` statement. In this context, it is a `Let` statement:

```
With x
    .SomeThing = New Something
End With
```

Note that in the VBA grammar, the keyword `Let` is optional (obsolete):

```
let-statement = ["Let"] l-expression "=" expression
```

In a `Set` statement, the `Set` keyword is required:

```
set-statement = "Set" l-expression "=" expression
```

Inside of a `With` block, the `l-expression` is basically the UDT member, although the exact same behavior applies if `x` is used directly.

When evaluating a `Let` expression, the semantics are described in [section 5.4.3.8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177357.aspx):

> *Static Semantics.*
>
> This statement is invalid if any of the following is true:
>
> - <expression> cannot be *evaluated to a simple data value (section* 5.6.2.2 *)*.

Following that to [5.6.2.2 (Evaluation to a simple data value)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200207.aspx), the following runtime semantics apply (applicable rule only):

> *Runtime semantics.*
>
> At runtime, the simple data value’s value and value type are
>   determined based on the classification of the expression, as follows:
>
> - If the expression’s value type is a specific class:
>
>   - If the source object has a public default Property Get or a public
>       default function, and this default member’s parameter list is
>       compatible with an argument list containing 0 parameters, the simple
>       data value’s value is the result of evaluating this default member as
>       a simple data value.
>   - Otherwise, if the source object does not have a public default
>       Property Get or a public default function, runtime error 438 (Object
>       doesn’t support this property or method) is raised.

Thus the runtime error 438 for `SomeThing As Something`.

With the `Collection`, the `Let` static semantics still apply, but it fails the **static** semantics of 5.6.2.2 (which gives the compile error). Again, the preceding inapplicable semantics are omitted:

> *Static semantics.* The following types of expressions can be evaluated to produce a simple data value:
>
> - An expression classified as a value expression may be evaluated as a simple data value based on the following rules:
>
>   - If the declared type of the expression is a specific class:
>   - If this class has a public default Property Get or function and this default member’s parameter list is compatible with an argument
>       list containing 0 parameters, simple data value evaluation restarts as
>       if this default member was the expression.

The default member of `Collection` is a function (`.Item`) that takes a single parameter `Index`. In this code, the parameter is not provided, so the argument list is incompatible:

```
With x
    .SomeThing = New VBA.Collection
End With
```

Thus the `Argument Not Optional` compile error.

Answer (score 1):

In typing up the question, it struck me that the `VBA.Collection` had a default member. Thus, the compiler was interpreting the `.Something = New VBA.Collection` as an *assignment* to the default member... except that the `Item` is an indexed property. That explains why we get `Argument not optional` which would be quite a strange error to get with a `Set` statement.

In contrast, a VBA class module might not have a default member at all, so that there is no indexed property + default member to trigger a compile-time error. However, it also means that the bad syntax won't be caught until runtime.